# Acknowledge messages

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have implemented a simple acknowledge pattern, it works like this:

The client receiver thread sends an `ackRequest` with an `ackID` saves the ackID in a doubly linked list with a callback and sends then the message to the client. Once the client receives the message it responds with an `ackResponse` and the `ackID` linked to it. When the client receiver thread receives a `ackResponse` it looks the `ackID` in his queue up and executes the callback (if found).

This works just fine if the thread wants an acknowledge from the client and vice versa:

```
CLIENT1  <---- ackRequest  (ID=1234) -----  CLIENT1 THREAD
                                             \- add 1234 to queue with callback

CLIENT1  ----- ackResponse (ID=1234) ---->  CLIENT1 THREAD
                                             \- look 1234 in queue up
                                              \- execute callback
```

But it is not possible for client receiver thread #1 to get an acknowledge from client #2 because the acknowledge message will end up in the client receiver thread #2 and not #1:

```
CLIENT1  <---- ackRequest  (ID=1234) -----  CLIENT2 THREAD
                                             \- add 1234 to queue with callback

CLIENT1  ----- ackResponse (ID=1234) -----> CLIENT1 THREAD
                                             \- look 1234 in queue up
                                              \- not found because it's in client's 2 thread
```

I don't know how I should solve this problem, one idea I had was a global acknowledge queue but this sounds like a bad idea to me.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user3386109 Client2 got it from the database where all users are linked to their socket fd. So it is possible.

Comment: @user3386109 why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @user3386109 Why does this matter for this problem?

Comment: @user3386109 Sorry, but I do not understand you... can you explain it to me please?